# Correct way to get emacs 16 color support inside tmux?

Tags: emacs, tmux, xterm

I'm trying to get a custom color-theme (solarized) setup for my emacs that utilizes a 16 color palette, which I've already set up for my terminal (gnome-terminal).

When running emacs from a normal terminal with `TERM=xterm-256color`, I can correctly get `M-x list-colors-display` to show all 16 ansi colors, e.g. red, green, brightgreen, brightred, etc.

However, when running it from within tmux and `TERM=screen-256color`, `M-x list-colors-display` only lists the basic 8 colors, and is missing the extended bright colors.  Under both settings, evaluating `(display-color-cells)` reports 256 colors.  The only references to the bright colors that I can find are in lisp/term/xterm.el and lisp/term/rxvt.el, so it would seem the issue is in the `TERM` setting.

For tmux to work properly the `TERM` must be set to screen or screen-256color, so setting TERM differently is out.  I have had some luck using an alias:

> `alias emacs='TERM=xterm-256color emacs'`

Is there a better way than this to force emacs to allow the use of all 16 ansi colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, the additional colors are configured by a TERM-specific library file (e.g. *term/lisp*). Newer versions of GNU Emacs includes a *term/screen* that re-uses the color definitions from *term/xterm*, but it sounds like your version of Emacs does not do this.

If you do not want to upgrade to a newer Emacs, then you can probably just use the content from [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/03101250a0c5bcc05f00) that includes a `term/screen.el` and a bit that you can put in your `.emacs` to enable it; that version of `term/screen.el` also includes a few of the key definitions that you might find useful if you enable *tmux*’s `xterm-keys` option.

The core bits of the code look like this:

```
;;; .emacs addition
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")

;;; ~/.emacs.d/lisp/term/screen.el
(load "term/xterm") 
(defun terminal-init-screen ()
  (xterm-register-default-colors)
  (tty-set-up-initial-frame-faces))
```

Comment: I do sometimes have to use version 23, which appears to be missing the screen definitions as you mentioned.  I'll give the solution you posted a try.  Thanks!

Comment: As a follow up, the solution you posted is working fine as far as color support goes.  One problem I have noticed using this approach is that emacs appears to lose the ability to support underlined faces when running using this method, but using the alias approach works fine.  I've tried hunting down where underline support is defined but haven't had any luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @agrubb: Emacs is probably using a terminfo entry for your active TERM (e.g. `screen-256color`) that includes an `ncv` capability that says that the terminal can not support underlining and color at the same time; this causes Emacs to forgo underlining in favor of bold (see the `defface underline` in `faces.el`). You can check your terminfo entry with `tput ncv` (ideally, to support underlining you need -1, or a number where the the “2 bit” is off). In emacs you can use `M-x : (display-supports-face-attributes-p '(:underline t))` to check for underline support.

Comment: @agrubb: The terminfo entry in newer releases of ncurses clears `ncv` from its `screen` entries, so I guess your Emacs binary is using an older version if the terminfo database. You could build a custom entry that clears `ncv` with a command like this: `{ infocmp -x screen-256color; printf '\t%s\n' 'ncv@,'; } > /tmp/t && tic -x /tmp/t` (when run as non-root, it will write a new `screen-256color` entry under `~/.terminfo/`). You can get an overview of the faces with `M-x list-faces-display` to check how (e.g.) `underline` is shown.

Comment: That was the problem.  Building the custom terminfo entry did the trick.  Thanks!